# How do you do Unit Testing with ASP.NET Core and AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, moq, xunit.net

I have written my first microservice (Web API) in ASP.NET core 3 that uses my AWS DynamoDB.
I have a repository and controller (and more but I think you only need this information):

**Controller:**

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class FollowersController : Controller
{
    private IFollowersRepository _repository;
    private IConfiguration _configuration;


    public FollowersController(IFollowersRepository repository, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    
    

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Follower>> GetAllFollowers(Guid userId)
    {
        return await _repository.All(userId);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Create")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(FollowerInputModel model)
    {
        await _repository.Add(model);
        SQSProcessor processor = new SQSProcessor(_configuration);
        await processor.SQSPost(model);
        return Ok(model);
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("Delete")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(FollowerInputModel follower)
    {
        await _repository.Remove(follower);
        SQSProcessor processor = new SQSProcessor(_configuration);
        await processor.SQSRemove(follower);
        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

**Repository:**
public class FollowersRepository : IFollowersRepository
{

```
    private readonly AmazonDynamoDBClient _client;
    private readonly DynamoDBContext _context;

    public FollowersRepository()
    {

        _client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
        _context = new DynamoDBContext(_client);
    }

    public async Task Add(FollowerInputModel entity)
    {
        var follower = new Follower
        {
            UserId = entity.UserId,
            FollowerId = entity.FollowerId,
        };
        
         await _context.SaveAsync(follower);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Follower>> All(Guid userId)
    {
        return await _context.QueryAsync<Follower>(userId).GetRemainingAsync();
    }

    public async Task Remove(FollowerInputModel entity)
    {
        var follower = new Follower
        {
            UserId = entity.UserId,
            FollowerId = entity.FollowerId,
        };
        var _follower = await _context.LoadAsync<Follower>(follower);
        await _context.DeleteAsync(_follower);
    }
```

Now I get very confused about what to test and how to test it since there does not really happens much logic within the controller or the repository. Do I even need to write tests and if so can somebody link me to an example that has such tests for the remove and add methods of the class that I should test?

I have read the other post about this but could not help me really.

Thanks in advance!